What is going on behind this numerical integration?
I am calculating the value of the integral
∫₀¹ ∫₁² (r - u)r drdu
I would like to understand how the following error is handled in R.
Looking around the forum, I realized that a vectorization of the first of the two integrals (in r) is required to compute the second one (in u). Therefore I assume that the following code is the correct way of solving the calculation.
fI <- function(u) {
  integrand <- function(r, u) {
    (r - u)*r
  }
  sapply(X=u, function(z) {
    integrate(f=integrand, lower=1, upper=2, u=z)$value
  })
}

integrate(f=fI, lower=0, upper=1)

which returns
1.583333 with absolute error < 1.8e-14.

The former being also the correct value according to Mathematica.
However, I could notice that even when incorrectly defining fI without vectorization, a small trick allows the integral to be calculated (I assume wrongly)
fI <- function(u) {
  integrand <- function(r, u) {
    (r - u) * r
  }
  integrate(f=integrand, lower=1, upper=2, u=u)$value
}

integrand2 <- function(u) {
  rep(1, length(u))*fI(u=u)
}

integrate(f=integrand2, lower=0, upper=1)

which delivers a different result
1.5 with absolute error < 1.7e-14.

Can anybody explain me what is going on in the second case and what is the value passed as u in fI(u=u) inside the integrand function? I understand that in this way u cannot take a range of values.
I need to understand this mechanism because my actual calculation is a bit more involved and I would need to understand what is going on in this simplified case.

R's integration uses the double precision approximation to the integral I
by applying the 21-point  kronrod rule (resk) obtained by optimal addition              of abscissae to the 10-point gauss rule. These points are chosen as the roots of  of the orthogonal polynomial associated with the specific Gauss quadrature rule being used. (I don't remember which rule R uses). These points are fixed in all cases.
Could not find a function to generate these points in R. But I am sure there should be a way to compute/generate them.
Anyway the points can be found by simply googling 21 point gauss kronrod values
these nodes and their weights are given as:




node  
weights 




1
0
0.149445554002917


2
±0.148874338981631
0.147739104901338


3
±0.29439286270146
0.14277593857706


4
±0.433395394129247
0.134709217311473


5
±0.562757134668605
0.123491976262066


6
±0.679409568299024
0.109387158802298


7
±0.780817726586417
0.0931254545836976


8
±0.865063366688985
0.07503967481092


9
±0.930157491355708
0.054755896574352


10
±0.973906528517172
0.0325581623079647


11
±0.995657163025808
0.0116946388673719




R uses these nodes to compute the appropriate   values that are then passed to the function before multiplying by the weignts.
Check the integrate.c R's source code, and note that these same values are listed.
The function is computed at these points once scaled over to the domain given:
Example:
f <- function(x) {
     print(sort(x)); cat("\n")
     cos(x)
}
 integrate(f, 0, 1)
 [1] 0.002171418 0.013046736 0.034921254 0.067468317 0.109591137 0.160295216 0.218621433 0.283302303
 [9] 0.352803569 0.425562831 0.500000000 0.574437169 0.647196431 0.716697697 0.781378567 0.839704784
[17] 0.890408863 0.932531683 0.965078746 0.986953264 0.997828582

0.841471 with absolute error < 9.3e-15


Now lets use the method above:
nodes <- c(0.995657163025808, 0.973906528517172, 0.930157491355708, 0.865063366688985, 0.780817726586417, 0.679409568299024, 0.562757134668605, 0.433395394129247, 0.29439286270146, 0.148874338981631, 0)
weights <- c(0.0116946388673719, 0.0325581623079647, 0.054755896574352, 0.07503967481092, 0.0931254545836976, 0.109387158802298,0.123491976262066, 0.134709217311473, 0.14277593857706, 0.147739104901338, 0.149445554002917)

a <- 0
b <- 1
midpoint <- (a + b) * .5
diff_range <- (b - a) * .5
all_nodes <- c(nodes, -nodes[-11])
all_weights <- c(weights, weights[-11])
(x <- all_nodes * diff_range + midpoint)

[1] 0.002171418 0.013046736 0.034921254 0.067468317 0.109591137 0.160295216 0.218621433 0.283302303
[9] 0.352803569 0.425562831 0.500000000 0.574437169 0.647196431 0.716697697 0.781378567 0.839704784
[17] 0.890408863 0.932531683 0.965078746 0.986953264 0.997828582

sum(all_weights * cos(x)) * diff_range
[1] 0.841471

Compare the results of the two. Note that the method presented is a simplification of what is happening. There are other various values computed which are used to reduce the error in the konrod approximation.

Well in this case if you integrate integrand2 as I showed you, you get a different value (1.5) than calculating the integral applying the method (1.52). In the second case, the function, which does not accept vector-valued inputs, is simply evaluated at the midpoint of x - unclear why! In the former case, where integrate is called, the result 1.5 is even more unjustified.

@MrFrog Notice that your second case is not making use of gauss quadrature its assuming that the function is constant which is not the case. The results of the inner integral is not a constant,

Yes, ok but a constant for f(u) when u = ?.

@MrFrog at u = 5/9 . Is that what you are looking for?

Why u=5/9? I am trying to understand

@MrFrog What exactly are you trying to understand? I answered this question like 2 days ago. I do not remember all the details. Perhaps consider asking a new question

Why is the value passed for u = 5/9? I am trying to understand the results I get and how R works

@MrFrog sorry, when I gave 5/9, I was giving the value where fI(u) = 1.5. I doubt R is doing that. it gets the value from the computation of the inner integrand. ie integrate from 1 to 2  of (r-u)* r where u is the shifted nodes given in the solution above ie all_nodes. this will give you the results 1.5
